# Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK in android studio

Tags: android

when i try to run my app i faced unknown of error like this:-
`Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK D:\andriod App\JsonArray\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk`.  and one of another problem come in like this:-

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt
>       File 1: D:\andriod App\JsonArray\app\libs\commons-logging-1.2.jar
>       File 2: D:\andriod App\JsonArray\app\libs\commons-codec-1.9.jar

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.catalyst.com.jsonarray"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }}dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add below code to your gradle file :

```
android {
     packagingOptions { 
         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' 
         exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' 
     }
 }
```

Edited :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
}
```

Remove jar(commons-logging and commons-codec ) from libs folder and add this gradle dependency.

Thanks.

Comment: @ Anand Jain : Check edited answer. Try that also..!!

Answer (score 2):

You can add this code in your gradle file:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```