# Multiple dex files on Android Studio using OpenCV Library

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-studio

So, my scheme is this:
I've got my app **A** project which uses the Java OpenCV library, and a module **B** which is a library module that uses Java OpenCV library as well.

My settings of modules is this one: In the app **A** I compile the module **B** and the **B** modules compiles de Java OpenCV library, but I get:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Users/rafaelruizmunoz/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /Users/rafaelruizmunoz/crossproject/Android/demoapp/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/Users/rafaelruizmunoz/crossproject/Android/demoapp/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
>     Error Code:
>       2
>     Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/opencv/BuildConfig;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

[image]

**Gradle scripts:**

**(App - A)**

```
 dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
        compile project(':ReaderLib_OpenCVBased')
    }
```

**(Module - B)**

```
 dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile project(':openCVLibrary249')
    }
```

So my main problem is that I can't use the **OpenCV** library with a module which compiles the OpenCV library, how should I do it?

Comment: are you using proguard ?

Answer (score 2):

You have problem of multidex file so please add below dependency to your app Gradle file.

```
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Also add this line:

```
defaultConfig {

    applicationId 'pkg'
    minSdkVersion 
    targetSdkVersion 
    versionCode 
    versionName 

    // Enable MultiDexing:  https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Thanks..!!

Comment: Good one, but now it's saying:
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/opencv/BuildConfig.class

, why?

Comment: @ Rafael Ruiz : Can you please post full error in your question? Please refer this answer also you getting this error -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/32581498/4018207

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1'
```

And below unchanged

```
    defaultConfig {

    applicationId 'pkg'
    minSdkVersion 
    targetSdkVersion 
    versionCode 
    versionName 

    // Enable MultiDexing:  https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Have a look here

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81804

Comment: Same error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/opencv/BuildConfig.class

Comment: @RafaelRuiz Okay .Check this Url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718825/how-to-resolve-java-util-zip-zipexception and https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/building/multidex.html#testing